# Constraining correlations between two latent variables

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, mediation, suppressor

I am running a multiple mediation model using SEM, where my 2 latent variables are my mediators, and my main predictor and my outcome are both exogenous variables. I have specified that my LVs are correlated, and when I do this I end up with a suppression effect wherein the relationship between my LVs and the main outcome change dramatically compared to the single mediation models with just one LV. I have tried to mitigate this in two ways, but I am not sure if either of them are statistically "legal." I have tried the following:

1. Not specifying that my latent variables are correlated at all. This seems to mitigate the suppression issue, and the model fit remains the same.
2. Constraining the correlation between my LVs to 0.3, which mitigates the suppression issue and improves the model fit.

Are either of these methods statistically justified?

Many thanks!

Comment: If the fit doesn't change, then the correlation is not statistically significant. Is that correct?

Comment: The correlation is statistically significant. r=0.7, p<0.001

Comment: In that case I'm surprised that the fit doesn't change. Are you sure?

Comment: The fit changes, but only very slightly. I believe the RMSEA increases a bit and the CFI and TLI both decrease slightly, but nothing changes to be outside of the realm of acceptability.

Comment: But the chi-square will change significantly?

Answer (score 0):

On the question is it an acceptable practice to constrain, or specify, the correlation between your latent variables, the answer is perhaps yes, if presented in a different analysis context.

As a particular example for the affirmative, I cite this work: [Bayesian latent variable modelling of multivariate spatio-temporal variation in cancer mortality](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.111.7208&rep=rep1&type=pdf), to quote:

> The use of Bayesian approach to inference provides us with great flexibility in modelling options and a rich output for inferential purposes, in particular, various spatially and temporally correlated prior distributions for the latent factors and residual error terms to capture the geographical and time series structure.

where gaining flexibility in your analysis appears to be one of your goals.